# Sharepoint List - Generate Unique # identifier in Column A based on Column B. Same # if duplicate

Tags: sharepoint, calculated-columns, uniqueidentifier, autonumber

I am working on creating a tracker, my client has requested the data be on sharepoint list for ease of viewing.

In order to organize the tracker on the Sharepoint List, I would like to generate an autonumber (calculated column) in one column, I've given it the naming convention of Task ID.

For my logic - Task ID (Column A) will be based on another column, known as Title (Column B),

IF column B is not the same then Column A should generate a new number. IF Column B is duplicative then Column A should generate the same number.

I would like the Task ID (Column A) to generate something like this: "TSK-0001"

Is this possible to create for sharepoint list? Thanks again for any help. Let me know if there is still more questions to be answered before figuring out the calculated value.

Note: Column B is a single line of text

I have not tried anything to this point. I have seen that you can generate random numbers via the Left(Right(),X,X) function.

I would like the outcome to show this in Sharepoint List:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/quzGg.png

Comment: Provide some example entities, please - what you want to show or see after implantation you task

Comment: @Maxim Added example outcome !

Comment: All sharepoint lists has autoincrement ID field . You can create field for prefix (some category, for example) to combine ID with prefix in calculated field or store prefix value in calculated field formula. For leading zero you should mesure length of ID and add missing zero at left of ID value. Or you can create spfx extension and with js code create any value your want.

Comment: I'll look into that further. My only dilemma that the Title Column is going to be recurring several times before discontinuation.

Comment: For now I am not confident in how to create said formula(s). Additionally for context,  Title Column is going to be recurring several times before discontinuation. e.g., Lets say Column Title name is Project1 and what my client wants  to do is create a new line item each time a new action has occurred for Project1. And so the task ID will capture them as the category. Further down the road, i will want to  create a personalized version of the tracker for all people inputting their projects so they can track by their individual task IDs.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/examples-of-common-formulas-in-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v=office.14)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To solve this issue, I decided to treat it like a lock box. I utilized 5 columns that make a request combo unique through the LEN function. From there, I created a basic algebraic equation to keep them individualistic. The client averages just under 1500 line items per year and the formula worked to that extent. Overall, I am able input a text value into column b that will categorize it properly much like a large number for tracking a package. This will be a temporary solution until the client finally gets Power Automate and I can do something like a countif(max(vlookup())) function.